# Difference between 'is_array' and '\is_array'

Tags: php

```
if(is_arrray($arr)
{
    //code...
}

 if(\is_array($arr)
 {
     //code..
 }
```

The two conditions gives same result. But, exactly, what is the difference?

Comment: `\is_array` says exactly: bring me the `is_array` function that is located in global namespace. Whereas `\Eldhose\is_array` might be another function created under `Eldhose` namespace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use namespace you can override local functions in you namespace, when you use \ you are calling to the global one.

You can read more about in [namespaces.fallback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

This is a little example extracted from php.net:

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;

const E_ERROR = 45;
function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str) - 1;
}

echo E_ERROR, "\n"; // prints "45"
echo INI_ALL, "\n"; // prints "7" - falls back to global INI_ALL

echo strlen('hi'), "\n"; // prints "1"
if (is_array('hi')) { // prints "is not array"
    echo "is array\n";
} else {
    echo "is not array\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: +1: Didn't know PHP had, neither ever cared to work with namespaces. But certainly a useful piece of information that definitely answers the question.

Comment: @Derija93 namespace are very important: http://www.phptherightway.com/#namespaces

Comment: Ambiguity usually isn't any of my concern since I rather concentrate on client-side scripts. Whenever I do write PHP, it is closely tied to a highly specific task within a defined environment, and the code usually isn't shared. Thus, why care to use namespaces if prefixing those three functions works just as well?